# Glyphicon with small badge

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to make a notification glyphicon with a badge with the notification number like this[image]

I found this code on another question here in stackoverflow but with a long text the badge don't keep his position
Someone can help me with a responsive solution
**The button for the glyphicon is not neccesary on the contrary is better without it**

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="font-size:36px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
</button>
<span class="badge badge-notify">9</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.badge-notify{
   background:red;
   position:relative;
   top: -20px;
   left: -35px;
   width: auto;
  }
```

Comment: It is a common practice to limit the content placed inside the badge, rather than trying to make it work for long texts. For example, most sites will represent numbers up to 9, and for larger numbers they will simply display 9+.

Comment: Do you need something like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/WegwVAt.png)? Have a look at my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add the parent `position: relative` and give the badge itself a `position: absolute`. Something like this would do:

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
.badge-holder {position: relative; display: inline-block;}
.badge {position: absolute; top: -10px; right: -10px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="badge-holder">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="font-size:36px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
  </button>
  <span class="badge badge-notify">9</span>
</div>
```

Or if you want something exactly as how you have asked:

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
.badge-holder {position: relative; display: inline-block;}
.badge {position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 12px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="badge-holder">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="font-size:36px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
  </button>
  <span class="badge badge-notify">9</span>
</div>
```

It's indeed wise to limit the content of the badge to shortened ones. Like after `9` make it `9+` or something.